# discord.js/node.js make code wait until sql query returns result

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I am working on a discord.js bot, and I'm storing a bunch of information on various servers in a database. The problem is, that the code doesn't wait for the database to return the results. In the current situation, I'm trying to check if the server specific prefix checks out.

I tried using `async` and `await` at various places, but those didn't work. If I could, I'd rather not use `.then()`, because I don't really want to put all the commands inside a `.then()`.

```
const { Client, Attachment, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const config = require("./config.json")

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'botdb'
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("I'm ready")
})

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

    let msg = message.content.split(" ");
    let command = msg[0];
    let prefix;

    con.query(`SELECT * FROM serversettings WHERE ServerID = ${message.guild.id}`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        prefix = rows[0].Prefix;
        console.log(prefix)
    })

    console.log(`Prefix: ${prefix}, Command: ${command}`)
    if (command === `${prefix}examplecommand`) {
        //Do something
    }
    //Other code that uses prefix and command
}
```

It should log the prefix first, and then the `Prefix: ${prefix}, Command: ${command}` part, but it does it the other way around, so the examplecommand doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is caused by the fact that what's outside your query callback is executed immediately after the call. Keep in mind the `mysql` module is callback-based.

**Possible Solutions**

- Place the code inside the callback so it's executed when the query is completed.
- Wrap the query in a promise and await it.

  ```js
  function getGuild(guildID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      con.query(`SELECT * FROM serversettings WHERE ServerID = '${guildID}', (err, rows) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);

        resolve(rows);
      });
    });
  }

  const [guild] = await getGuild(message.guild.id)  // destructuring 'rows' array
    .catch(console.error);

  console.log(guild.prefix);
  ```
- Use a Promise-based version of a MySQL wrapper, like [`promise-mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql). You could use it the same way as the code above, without worrying about coding your own Promises.

  ```js
  const [guild] = await con.query(`SELECT * FROM serversettings WHERE serverID = '${message.guild.id}'`)
    .catch(console.error);

  console.log(guild.prefix);
  ```

Comment: Thank you, with some minor modifications the first option worked perfectly. Just one question. Is there a reason why the `[guild]` is in squared brackets?

Comment: The brackets are part of the destructuring syntax. Basically, in this case it declares `guild` as the first element of the array returned by the query. For more about destructuring, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). (It's much more useful in other contexts.)